# Brew services won't start

Tags: php, homebrew

After installing `redis` I noticed that the `services` are not active and I have an `error` status for:

- `dnsmasq`
- `nginx`
- `php` (which is php8.x)
- `php@7.4`
- `redis`

I've tried everything I found on the internet, including SO but with no luck.

I tried:

- reinstalling each service
- `launchctl unload` and `launchctl load` - `~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist` (I have tried this for each service)
- `brew doctor` says: *Your system is ready to brew.*
- `launchctl enable <service target>`

However if I run `sudo brew services list` everything works except `mysql` and `php` (PHP 8.x)

When I try to start each services individually with `brew services start SERVICE NAME` I get the following error. Here's for `php`

```
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error

Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501
 
/Users/mvpop/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist` exited with 5.
```

I ran out of ideas of what I could try in order to be able to start the services.

Any advice would much appreciate.

Thanks!

UPDATE - I just removed and reinstalled all services one by one and I have the same error when trying to start them:

```
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error

Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501
 
/Users/mvpop/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist` exited with 5.
```

Comment: Hi Marian, did your issue resolved? 
I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

I've received the same error with my valet installation. The sequence of step i used is ...

1. valet stop
2. brew unlink php@7.3 php@7.4 php
3. brew link --force --overwrite php@8.2
4. brew services stop php
5. brew services start php@8.2
6. composer global update
7. rm -f ~/.config/valet/valet.sock
8. valet install

I think the step no 4 is the one that solve the issues. Somehow when unlink brew unable to stop the service automatically.